# Refresh excel powerquery using microsoft-graph excel API

Tags: excel, microsoft-graph-api, powerquery

I was wondering if Graph API for excel supports powerquery. For example if there were a number of powerqueries in the workbook with the data loaded in the excel data model.
Is it possible to do the following:

- Use graph api to refresh the excel data model by triggering a power
  query to run? I see there is a way to refresh pivottables so I guess
  if the above worked then any dashboard items that use the refreshed
  content will change also?
- An extension of the above would be to supply parameters to a parameterised power query. But maybe I am expecting too much here?